# Add mondgoc and libbson to yocto distribution

Tags: mongodb, yocto

I am new to yocto and I am trying to add Mongo C driver as a library to my yocto image and SDK. 
I have found the instructions to build mongo C driver(http://mongoc.org/libmongoc/current/installing.html#building-from-a-release-tarball ) but I would like to do it through a yocto recipe. Could you please give me some hints?

For information I am building an image for an ARM target.

Answer (score 0):

Use recipetool or the more featureful devtool, as described in the documentation at http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/dev-manual/dev-manual.html#new-recipe-writing-a-new-recipe